# WPF page fixed layout with MVVM

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application with MVVM that have several pages with common layout e.g. page header and navigation buttons (the middle part of each page is different).
How can I implement the fixed page layout once and extend it in the different pages with MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to do this is to create a main window or page and then render user controls inside of that using a content control and data templates. Set the content control binding to a property on the main window's view model. You'll need an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, of course, then a main window or application view model, some child view models, a content control in your main window or page, then user controls to represent your views...sort of this this:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    protected virtual void VerifyPropertyName(string property)
    {
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[property] == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(property + " property doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
}

public interface IPageViewModel
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Page1ViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get { return "View 1"; } }
}

public class Page2ViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get { return "View 1"; } }
}

public class ApplicationViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private IPageViewModel currentViewModel;
    public IPageViewModel CurrentViewModel 
    { 
        get
        { 
            return this.currentViewModel = 
                this.currentViewModel 
                ?? new Page1ViewModel();
        }
        set
        {
            this.currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        this.CurrentViewModel = new Page1ViewModel()
    }
}
```

Your main window or page would have its view model (DataContext) set to an instance of ApplicationViewModel. The content control would then be bound to the CurrentViewModel property of the ApplicationViewModel, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfScratchApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfScratchApp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{DynamicResource AppViewModel}"
    >
   <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <app:ApplicationViewModel x:Key="AppViewModel" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Buttons and stuff -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then, create UserControl's corresponding to each of those views:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfScratchApp.Views.Page1View"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="150">

    <!-- Cool controls and stuff in here... -->
</UserControl>
```

(Create a similar one corresponding to Page2ViewModel, called "Page2View".)  Then, map the view models to the views like this in your app.xaml, or a merged dictionary.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfScratchApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PortfolioManager"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Page1ViewModel}">
                <views:Page1View />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Page2ViewModel}">
                <views:Page2View />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When you change the CurrentViewModel property in the application view model, it should change the value of the binding for the control control. WPF will use the data template corresponding to the type represented by the CurrentViewModel property to render the content.

So, you can have your buttons all set up in the main window and coded to operate on the CurrentViewModel. Then, change out the CurrentViewModel based upon the content you want to show.